# Is it possible to call a Blazor component through a parameter passed to a component?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I would like to be able to send the name of a Blazor component to another component and have it render. Something like:

```
@page "/"
@using MyProject.Shared.Navigation

<ContentLeftNav UseNav="Navigation1">
Content
</ContentLeftNav>
```

Where Navigation1.razor is a component rendered in a certain place within the ContentLeftNav.razor component. I've seen articles where `switch` is recommended to alternate between components, but I'd like to avoid writing out a `switch` statement for all possible navigation components. Is what I'm wanting to do even possible?

Comment: You could use the render tree directly but it is cumbersome. You should use a template like the answer suggests

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

Have your ContentLeftNav component specify multiple render fragments. For example:

```
<h3>ContentLeftNav</h3>
<div id="Content-left-body">
    @Content
</div>
<div id="Content-left-nav">
    @Navigation
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment Navigation { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment Content { get; set; }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
<ContentLeftNav>
    <Navigation>
        @if (true)
        {
            <p>Some navigation content</p>
        }
        else
        {
            <p>Some other navigation content</p>
        }
    </Navigation>
    <Content>
        <p>Some other content</p>
    </Content>
</ContentLeftNav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative. It's not great, but it will work:

```
ContentLeftNav.razor

<nav>
   @RenerNav()
</nav>
<div>
   @ChildContent
</div>

@code {
   [Parameter] public Type NavComponent {get; set; }
   [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
    
    private RenderFragment RenderNav() => builder =>
    {
        builder.OpenComponent(0, ComponentToRender);
        builder.CloseComponent();
    };
}
```

```
Index.razor

@page "/"
@using MyProject.Shared.Navigation

<ContentLeftNav NavComponent="@typeof(Navigation1)">
Content
</ContentLeftNav>
```

When rendering the `ContentLeftNav` you can send in the type of any component, and the `ContentLeftNav` will render an instance of that component.